# Cannot Select Linked When Sync Selection Is Enabled

Tags: animation, uv

So, I'm currently developing a game with unity for which I created a bird, rigged it, and created several actions for it. I then unwrapped and textured it.
But now all the actions aren't working anymore! And whenever I try to rotate/move a bone all i get is the error message: "**Cannot select linked when sync selection is enabled**".
I think it might be related to the UV editor, but i have no clue what I should do there.
I hope anyone can help!

Comment: Can you share the blend file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's nothing about UV in this case. That's because you were trying to tweak pose in Rest position. Just remember to simply switch to Pose Position to continue tweaking. :)

Location:
Properties Editor > Object Data Tab > Skeleton > Pose position

[image]

BTW, there are indeed two such messages, located in:

- source/blender/editors/transform/transform_conversions.c
- source/blender/editors/uvedit/uvedit_ops.c

True, it's a strange message for bone transform system, which seems hard to make sense, probably needs to be improved.

---

**Edit:**

In the [latest build](http://builder.blender.org/download/), this puzzling message has been fixed as "**Cannot change Pose when 'Rest Position' is enabled**". So it is not an issue any more.