# How do I disable sync selection?

Tags: armature, selection-tools

I just started using blender and I'm trying to make an animation.

It's got it's armatures linked to the body via armature deform but whenever I try to move them in pose mode I get and error saying "cannot select linked when sync selection is enabled".

When I don't and I actually manage to move the armatures, the body doesn't move with them even though they're linked and every video I watched says that's all I need to do. Can anyone explain how to solve my problems here please?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4818/696). FYI.